# Scheduled Apex Limit Exceeded - Spring 15

Tags: scheduled-apex, spring15

After the Spring 15 update I am not able to schedule more than 5 apex jobs. These are **NOT BATCH** jobs but are being scheduled using the system.schedule. Before the update I was able to create more than 30 similar jobs but since the update i get the governor limit error.

has anyone encountered similar problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We encounter "You have exceeded the maximum number (5) of Apex scheduled jobs." even if we scheduled the Schedulable Apex Class through the UI [image]

This can be reproduced with a canonical code snippet like :

```
global with sharing class SchedTest implements Schedulable{
    global  void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      System.debug ('SchedTest date:' +DateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a bug then?

Answer (score 1):

We got this problem too. Tried opening a case in partner portal but didn't get beyond standard support which referred me to batch documentation and flexqueue. Just tried reopening the case again.  If you get any more into please tell me.